# Laravel 5.1 Override postRegistration for security even if not using Routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

In Laravel 5.1 if I'm not using registration in the application should I be overriding the public registration functions in AuthController to make public actions completely unavailable?  I'm not sure if there are any security issues with leaving them there.

For example in AuthController I've done this to make sure postRegistration could never somehow be accessed, but I don't know if I should/have to do this:

```
/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    abort(404);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Looking at the middleware I could also just set it so I only use the AuthenticatesUsers trait and drop the Registration trait so there's nothing to override with regards to registration in the AuthController (not sure of the implication of this change):

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    // REMOVE
    //use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    // ADD
    use AuthenticatesUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    ...
```

Just trying to find out what I should be doing and what that might mean with regards to security.

Comment: either way works and but I personally prefer the former one as it gives me flexibility of single method I want to disable. But for your need the second way works perfectly fine.

Comment: thanks @yangqi I'll keep both in mind and choose based on the situation.